# Line Not Found on while loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, while-loop

I've been trying to get this to work for a while. I'm putting in three parallel empty arrays and it errors out saying that there is no line found. It ONLY works when I change the while statement to the number of elements. I am trying to make arrays that are the size of 15, but only fill the first ten array portions.

Sorry if it sounds complicated, but basically I'm trying to say that the size of the array is 15, I only have 10 things to enter in the array, and the rest of them should be blank.

```
while (text.hasNext() && c < nameArray.length) {
        nameArray[count] = text.nextLine();
        intArray[count] = text.nextDouble();
        doubleArray[count] = text.nextInt();
        text.nextLine();
        c++;
    }
```

This does not work.

```
while (text.hasNext() && c < 9) {
        nameArray[count] = text.nextLine();
        intArray[count] = text.nextDouble();
        doubleArray[count] = text.nextInt();
        text.nextLine();
        c++;
    }
```

This does.

Comment: And what exactly is the value of `gameArray.length`?

Comment: All of the lengths are equal to 15.

Comment: Sounds like an "Off By One" error. Be sure to note that an array of length 15 has a highest index of 14.

Comment: Debug it and find out on which iteration this happens.

Comment: @ShaneHart glad to hear you've got it solved. Its not nessisary to edit the question to say it's solved; marking an answer as accepted marks it as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your read the file TWICE within a single loop. Remove the 2nd read:
fileText.nextLine();

Answer (score 0):

In the first version of your code, your try to read input 15 times, but it is entered only 10 times. So the scanner tries to read a new line but it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it doesn't work. If you need to cycle to the max between fileText length and gameArray length, you should use or instead of and and use an if in the loop.

Try something like this:

```
while (fileText.hasNext() || count < gameArray.length) {
        if (!fileText.hasNext()) {
           gameArray[count] = "";
           priceArray[count] = 0;
           stockArray[count] = 0;
        } else {
           gameArray[count] = fileText.nextLine();
           priceArray[count] = fileText.nextDouble();
           stockArray[count] = fileText.nextInt();
           fileText.nextLine();
        }
        count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not with the length of the array but with `fileTest.nextLine()`. After a certain point there is no `nextLine()` available. It works for the 1st 9 times but I guess all the lines are exhausted before you reach `array.length`. I would suggest just one condition in your while loop:

```
while(fileText.hasNext()) {
}
```

This way you would fill in only the amount actually present.

Answer (score 0):

Add another check with the second `fileText.nextLine()` to ensure that there is a line to read.

```
while (fileText.hasNext() && count < gameArray.length) {
    gameArray[count] = fileText.nextLine();
    priceArray[count] = fileText.nextDouble();
    stockArray[count] = fileText.nextInt();
    if ( fileText.hasNext() )
        fileText.nextLine();
    count++;
}
```

Comment: This works beautifully. I see what I did wrong. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: That is not correct. Yes, you will avoid exception. But you will read only every 2nd line. E.g. if there are 10 lines, you will fill only 5 elements in the array. 

@Shane Hart: Print out the array and check: you have only every 2nd line, not all.

Comment: @mentallurg - if you look a the OP you will see that the second piece of code "works" (which I interpret to mean "works correctly"). Since the OP does not include a sample input file I can only assume that every other line is blank and skipping lines is intended. If its not then by all means remove the second `readLine()` but I am not going to second guess what the OP's input is.

Comment: @MT0: No, id doesn't work. As I said, there is no exception. But every 2nd line will be skipped. Where as "Shane Hart" wants EACH line to be read. So your code will NOT work.